# Why won't this XML deserialize properly?

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Here's an example program showing what I'm trying to do:

http://pastebin.com/m1de1f3ba

The XML in the 'xml' string describes a list of items.  The PersonI2 type should be considered as extending the Person type, and therefore I want the XmlSerializer to deserialize the PersonI2 entries in the XML as PersonI2 objects... instead, the XmlSerializer throws an exception.  Why, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any reason you can't paste the example code in Stackoverflow?

Comment: It's not that long, you should paste the code example inline in your question.

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1477533/a-type-of-generic-list-deserialization-class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `XmlInclude` attribute to the Person class, to make the XmlSerializer aware of the PersonI2 class :

```
    [XmlType(AnonymousType = true, TypeName = "Person", Namespace = "")]
    [XmlInclude(typeof(PersonI2))]
    public class Person {
    ...
```

Comment: That doesn't work. You then get an InvalidaOperationException "Cannot include anonymous type 'XmlTester1.PersonI2'".

Comment: Also, I don't still don't know why this doesn't work but giving a base class (Person) knowledge of an extending class (PersonI2) feels wrong.

Comment: Actually, this does work if I also then make the AnonymousType's = false.  Thanks, Thomas!